# GraalVm Polyglot application - is it possible to evaluate kotlin script from java at runtime?

Tags: java, kotlin, graalvm

The GraalVM Polyglot API allows to embed and run code from guest languages in JVM-based host applications. I'm using `native-image` and additionally installed `python` so I can evaluate `js` and `python` scripts successfully from my java application via

```java
context.eval("js", "print('Hello JavaScript!');")
context.eval("python", "print('Hello Python!');")
```

It works just fine. However, if I try to evaluate the kotlin script in a similar way -

```java
context.eval("kotlin", "data class Company(val name: String, val year: Long);")
```

then it fails with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A language with id 'kotlin' is not installed. Installed languages are: [js, llvm, python].
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotEngineException.illegalArgument(PolyglotEngineException.java:128)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotEngineImpl.requirePublicLanguage(PolyglotEngineImpl.java:867)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotContextImpl.requirePublicLanguage(PolyglotContextImpl.java:899)
        at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotContextImpl.eval(PolyglotContextImpl.java:868)
        at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.eval(Context.java:345)
        at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.eval(Context.java:371)
```

I understand that it states that only `[js, llvm, python]` are available but I wonder whether it's possible to add anything to be able to evaluate `kotlin` script the similar way as well or not ? Or probably there is another way to evaluate a dynamic kotlin script at runtime from java application ?

Thank you.

Comment: https://hub.packtpub.com/getting-started-with-kotlin-programming/ try installing kotlin

Comment: Dear @Pierre, thank you for your help! However, I don't believe this can resolve the issue as the graalvm polyglot api requires the kotlin runtime implementation of truffle api and integration with polyglot api. Simple compiler install does not resolve the issue as it's not a simple call to compiler in terms of graalvm.